# How to search a user?

Tags: support, users, search

I need to have a look at the question of a user, who posted it some weeks ago. I didn't actually remember the question. But I know the user's name. So the only way to find that question is to find that user.

Is there any way to search a particular user in superuser ?

If not, why ?

Comment: Try the Users tab

Comment: http://superuser.com/users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click "Users" (on practically any page).
2. Enter the user name in the text field.

---

[image: Screenshot]